# Accurate synchronization of RPI CPU clock via NTP

Tags: raspberry-pi3, clock, ntp, real-time-clock

I'm going to be doing some clock programming with RPi. I'm fairly new to this area of coding so I want to check an assumption with the hive mind.

I will be using clock functions like "usleep" and "timer_create" with CLOCK_REALTIME as the clock ID. Can I safely assume that the clocking intervals will not be based on the CPU clock but on the internal (software) clock that can be modified and slewed by ntpd?

So, if I am running on a fairly accurate ntpd synchronization, any usleep will be as accurate as the precision achieved by the latest ntpd synchronization pass?

Further research indicates that NTP will slew the "system tick" or whatever that might be - to bring the system clock in line with NTP strata clocks over a reasonable time period.

Is it therefore the case that the timer intervals generated by timer_create, are affected by System Tick / NTP over the duration? The timer will be generating signals at a period of 250us over a period of 1 day at least. Ideally I want to achieve some level of synchronization between systems that are doing the same job.